# Date Range Parameter - including bounds in record selection

Tags: parameters, crystal-reports, report, selection, record

I'm using Crystal Reports 12.0.0.683 where I use a parameter of type date and set to **Allow Range Values**. Than I want to use it in **Record Selection Formula**. I'm setting **Include this value** and using this selection formula:

```
(not HasValue({?PARAM_DATE}) OR 
(
    if HasLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and HasUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) then
                ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} > Minimum({?PARAM_DATE})) and 
                        ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} < Maximum({?PARAM_DATE}))
    else if HasLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and not HasUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) then
                ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} > Minimum({?PARAM_DATE})) 
    else if HasLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and not HasUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and IncludesLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) then
                ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} >= Minimum({?PARAM_DATE})) 
    else if not HasLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and HasUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) then
                ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} < Maximum({?PARAM_DATE}))
    else if not HasLowerBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and HasUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) and IncludesUpperBound({?PARAM_DATE}) then
                ({VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} <= Maximum({?PARAM_DATE}))
))
```

I use `IncludesUpperBound` and `IncludesLowerBound` but it is still not selecting the right records.

For example, I have DATE_DUE 2012-03-30 and if I set the parameter 2012-03-30 and select include this value the records get filtered out.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not using Less-Than-Or-Equals/Greater-Than-Or-Equals everywhere so it's not going to include values *which are equal* to the max or min.

You can greatly simplify your code by doing this:

```
not(hasvalue({?PARAM_DATE}))
or {VIEW_REPORT_1.DATE_DUE} in {?PARAM_DATE}
```